# Name of file-object

Tags: ruby, file

Is it possible to get name of file, from object of `File` class?

For example, this method works good:

```
file = File::basename('/home/user/file.rb') 
p file # => file.rb
```

,but for object it doesn't work

```
file = File.new('/home/user/file.rb')
p file.basename
# => undefined method `basename' for #<File:/home/user/file.rb> (NoMethodError)
```

Comment: Does ruby not run on Windows these days?  I'm always curious why "scripting language" questions often include a linux tag.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There's no direct method IIRC. You can do

```
file = File.new('/home/user/file.rb')
p File.basename(file.path)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`path`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/File.html#M000041) instance method. (And call `File::basename` on that if you want only that part.)